# Problem when migrating SP2010 solution with WCF service to SP2013

Tags: 2013, web-services, migration, wcf

I have a VS2010 solution that has a few projects inside. One of them is a Sharepoint 2010 project that contains a WCF service generated from the [CKS template](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html).

I needed to migrate this solution to SP2013/VS2012 and so I did following [this guide](http://zimmergren.net/technical/upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions-to-sharepoint-2013).

Everything seemed to went well (no errors in the migration report). But noticed that the Sharepoint project has an error in the WCF service.

In the `MyService.svc.cs`

```
[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
// code...
}
```

The `[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]` attribute is not being found. In VS2010/SP2010 it was in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services` namespace. But now in VS2012/SP2013 there is no `Services` namespace inside `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` so I can't compile the service. I can't find where that class is now, or if has been removed or renamed.

Have you been able to migrate a SP2010 WCF service to SP2013 with no problem? Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it. The missing DLL was in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll`
But wasn't registered on VS, so you need to manually browse to the file.

Comment: Same problem here and can confirm that emzero solution works. Thanks, you saved me some lost time searching for that missing reference.